# Cannot save modified entity and new entity at the same time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, breeze

Let's imagine this EF model :

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Person")]
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    [InverseProperty("Adresses")]
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

A `Person` can have many `Address`.

I have a page in my application where I can manage `Person` and `Address` at the same time. In this page, I can create a `Person` and many `Address` in a single Breeze `saveChanges()` call.

**It works fine, except when I try to modify `Person` properties and add a new `Address` at the same time.**

This is the kindof `JObject` that Breeze Web API controller is receiving :

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "Id": -1,
      "PersonId": 3,
      "City": "Seattle",
      "Street": "Main Av",
      "Number": 1540,
      "entityAspect": {
        "entityTypeName": "Address:#MyApp.Models",
        "defaultResourceName": "Addresses",
        "entityState": "Added",
        "originalValuesMap": {},
        "autoGeneratedKey": {
          "propertyName": "Id",
          "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "Name": "Doe",
      "FirstName": "John",
      "Age": 32,
      "entityAspect": {
        "entityTypeName": "Person:#MyApp.Models",
        "defaultResourceName": "Persons",
        "entityState": "Modified",
        "originalValuesMap": {
          "FirstName": "William"
        },
        "autoGeneratedKey": {
          "propertyName": "Id",
          "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "saveOptions": {}
}
```

When calling `contextProvider.SaveChanges()` server-side, EF is complaining and refuse to accept my changes:

***AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.***

I have no idea what is going on, but it seems the way Breeze save these entities leads to duplicated entities in Entity Framework state manager.

**Does anyone have an idea on how to fix / work around this? Is it a bug in Breeze, or someting I'm not doing correctly?**

By the way, I'm running with Breeze 1.4.2 and Entity Framework 5.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer to my issue.

Actually, I was performing some validations before saving, using Breeze's `BeforeSaveEntities` delegate. Thing is, if you are retrieving an entity from `DBContext` during these validations and that the same entity is being saved later as part of the `JObject` submitted to Breeze controller, you run into the issue.

The workaround I use is to perform these validations as `AfterSaveEntities` hooks instead, and tell Breeze to use a transaction.

Comment: Another workaround is to use a different DB context to make your queries in the `BeforeSaveEntities` part. This is what I am doing and it works great!

Comment: As a matter of fact, I ended up doing this too. As my server must modify objects as well, I use 2 different contexts : a new instance to read entities for validations, and the one provided by ContextProvider to alter some properties of the entities being modified.

Comment: The only catch is you should set your second DB context not to track the entities.